# How can i move a window to a specific monitor (Ubuntu 20.04)?

Tags: 20.04, wmctrl

How do I move a window to a specific monitor with code? I have two screens where one needs to run an app in full screen, and the other needs to play a video in full screen.

Comment: That `wmctrl` that somebody (you?) added as a tag is a good starting point IMHO. Install that package (`sudo apt install wmctrl`) and look at the man page (`man wmctrl).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html) to achieve what you want.

I don't think there is any setting to move to one screen or another, you just need to set each window position (x and y position) and geometry (size). For example, run the following command in a terminal window

`xdotool search --name "WINDOW TITLE HERE" getwindowgeometry`

And then move the window around and between different monitors and you will see that it's just a different (top-left) x/y position depending on your monitor setup and resolution.

So you can experiment and code scripts to get the relevant window ID's and then set the position with the `windowmove` command and geometry with the `windowsize` command.

Comment: I have just seen your question is tagged with `wmctrl`. I am not too familiar with that but perhaps it's the same sort of position/geometry. Try `wmctrl -p -G -l` to list windows with geometry and move between monitors to see what changes and how it changes.

Answer (score 0):

I created [this](https://github.com/cix-code/win-pos) python script that reads a configuration json file and places each window to its desired place.

```
sudo apt install xdotool
git clone git@github.com:cix-code/win-pos.git
cd win-pos
cp sample.config.json config.json
nano config.json

# Run it this way or set it as delayed startup script
python3 winpos.py
```

Configuration example:

```
// Postitions the Spotify window on the second screen from the left, 
// on the second desktop centerly aligned.
{
    "name": "Spotify",
    "search_name": "^Spotify$",
    "screen": 1,
    "desktop": 1,
    "width": "50%",
    "height": "60%",
    "align": "center center"
},
```

The script simply runs the relevant `xrandr`, `xdotool` and `pgrep` commands to retrieve the screens layout, get the window ID and place the windows to their desired place.

Answer (score -1):

I created this rather complicated code to find the windows i wanted to move to a specific screen determined by the width in mm of the monitor (it will also resize to the correct resolution and set the app fullscreen):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time


def get(cmd): return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode('utf-8')


def adjust_resolution(name, res):  # name = DP-2, res: 1920x1080
    get(['xrandr', '--output', name, '--mode', res])


def edit_window(monitor, window_name, function):
    print('moving', window_name, 'to', monitor)
    get(['wmctrl', '-F', '-r', window_name, '-e', '100,' +
        monitor['x'] + ',' + monitor['y'] + ',600,600'])
    get(['wmctrl', '-F', '-r', window_name, '-b', function])


def get_monitors():
    screendata = [l.split() for l in get(['xrandr', '--current']
                                         ).replace('primary', '').splitlines() if ' connected' in l]
    monitors = []

    for i in range(len(screendata)):
        monitor = dict()
        [size, x, y] = screendata[i][2].split('+')
        monitor = {
            'name': screendata[i][0],
            'width': screendata[i][-3],
            'height': screendata[i][-1],
            'size': size,
            'x': x,
            'y': y
        }
        monitors.append(monitor)

    return monitors


def find_element_where(elements, key, value):
    return next((item for item in elements if item[key] == value), None)


def window_info_to_dict(info):
    _, _, x, y, width, height, _, *name = info.split()
    return {'x': x, 'y': y, 'width': width, 'height': height, 'name': ' '.join(name)}


def get_window_info():
    return list(map(window_info_to_dict, get(['wmctrl', '-l', '-G']).splitlines()))


# Constants:
main_monitor_width = '256mm'
controller_app = 'name_of_app'
video_player = 'VLC media player'
correct_resolution = '1920x1080'

# Variables:
did_remove_fullscreen = False

while True:
    try:
        # Get monitors:
        monitors = get_monitors()
        main_monitor = next(
            (monitor for monitor in monitors if monitor['width'] == main_monitor_width), None)
        secondary_monitor = next(
            (monitor for monitor in monitors if monitor['width'] != main_monitor_width), None)

        # print(main_monitor)
        # print(secondary_monitor)

        # Get windows:
        window_info = get_window_info()

        controller_app_window_info = find_element_where(
            window_info, 'name', controller_app)
        video_player_window_info = find_element_where(
            window_info, 'name', video_player)

        # Check if secondary monitor is the right size:
        if secondary_monitor and secondary_monitor['size'] != correct_resolution:
            print('Wrong resolution', secondary_monitor)
            adjust_resolution(secondary_monitor['name'], correct_resolution)

        # print(controller_app_window_info)
        # print(video_player_window_info)

        if main_monitor:
            if controller_app_window_info['x'] != main_monitor['x'] or controller_app_window_info['y'] != main_monitor['y'] or controller_app_window_info['width'] != '1920' or controller_app_window_info['height'] != '1080':
                print('Controller app is not positioned correctly')
                edit_window(main_monitor, controller_app, 'add,fullscreen')
        else:
            print('No primary monitor')

        if secondary_monitor:
            if video_player_window_info['x'] != secondary_monitor['x'] or video_player_window_info['y'] != secondary_monitor['y'] or video_player_window_info['width'] != '1920' or video_player_window_info['height'] != '1080':
                print('Video player is not positioned correctly')
                edit_window(secondary_monitor, video_player, 'add,fullscreen')
                did_remove_fullscreen = False
        else:
            print('No secondary monitor')
            if main_monitor and not did_remove_fullscreen:
                edit_window(main_monitor, video_player, 'remove,fullscreen')
                did_remove_fullscreen = True

    except Exception as e:
        print('An error occured', e)

    time.sleep(10)
```